# How do you make a Discord Bot not send a message when certain words are said (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a Discord Bot that posts a specific image once a chosen word is said. So far that all works great, but what I'm having trouble with is that I need to make a list of words from which it will **not** send a message if any of those words are stated. However I'm having trouble implementing this feature, and I can't seem to find any answers. This is my first time using JavaScript and making a Discord Bot, so it's not exactly my forte (I used a guide to set some of this up). So if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know. Thanks!

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.author.bot) return;
 if (message.content.match('Temple') || message.content.match('temple')) {
  message.channel.send(
   'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/278000731125186560/750883416744001606/A9a0P768eBgtgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg_1.png'
  );
 }

 const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
 const args = commandBody.split(' ');
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a function to check if `content` is include banned words or not. Use that function to check `message.content` before send the message.

```
const isIncludeBanWords = (content) => {
  const bannedWords = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
  for (const bannedWord of bannedWords) {
    if (content.indexOf(bannedWord) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The function will return `true` if `content` includes at least one `banned word`.

Final example:

```
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!";

const isIncludeBanWords = (content) => {
  const bannedWords = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
  for (const bannedWord of bannedWords) {
    if (content.indexOf(bannedWord) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

client.on("message", function (message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const isMatchKeyword = message.content.match("Temple") || message.content.match("temple");
  if (isMatchKeyword && !isIncludeBanWords(message.content)) { // match keyword and NOT include banned word
    message.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/278000731125186560/750883416744001606/A9a0P768eBgtgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg_1.png")
  }

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: I implemented the the function you posted into my code and inserted the banned words, but when testing the bot it seems to send the image regardless if the banned words are stated or not.

Comment: Never mind I got it to work! Apparently my banned words weren't saved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let triggers = ['word', 'word2', 'word3'];
client.on('message', (message) => {
 let isContain = triggers.some(checkInclude);
 if (isContain) message.channel.send('YES');

 function checkInclude(element, index, array) {
  return message.content.toUpperCase().includes(element.toUpperCase());
 }
});
```